# MySQL error code 1064 syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

This is a very specific question to the kind of code i have written for postgresql and i am migrating to mysql for project requirements.

The code written so far in mysql is as follows :

```
(select substring(dt,1,9) as dt,concat(vish,visl,visn) as vis,ip
    from assignment_walmart.b 
    where service='ss' and ua not like '%ktxn%' 
        and ua not like '%khte%' 
        and ua not like '%keynote%' 
        group by 1,2,3
    ) as A1

    left join // This is where it shows the error.

    (select ip,flag from 
    assignment_walmart.b1 
    group by 1,2    
    ) as A2

    on A1.ip=A2.ip
    where A2.flag is NULL
    group by 1,2;
```

The error is popping up near the naming of the two selected tables as "A1" and "A2", so i'm assuming it's not allowed in mysql.

Can you please help me with an alternate syntax for the above code as I have to use the two tables in this manner only to join in to get required results.

How exactly do i use alias or join 2 tables in such a manner which was clearly working in postgresql?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If that's all of your code, then consider it's basically `A1 left join a2`... that `A1` is not exactly legitimate sql. Try `select * from A1 left join ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a subquery joined to another query.  This shouldn't work in either database.  You need to wrap these in a `select` or something like that:

```
select A2.dt, A2.vis, count(*)
from (select substring(dt,1,9) as dt, concat(vish,visl,visn) as vis,ip
      from assignment_walmart.b 
      where service='ss' and ua not like '%ktxn%' 
          and ua not like '%khte%' 
          and ua not like '%keynote%' 
      group by substring(dt,1,9), concat(vish,visl,visn), ip
     ) as A1 left join // This is where it shows the error.
     (select ip,flag from 
      assignment_walmart.b1 
      group by ip, flag
     ) as A2
     on A1.ip=A2.ip
where A2.flag is NULL
group by A2.dt, A2.vis;
```

I am making a guess on what you want for the outer query and what the aggregation fields are.  It is a good idea to be explicit about which fields are being aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `SELECT ... FROM` on the outer query.

It looks you mean for your query to be of the form:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM ( inline view query ) A1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( inline view query ) A2
    ON A1.col = A2.col ...
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: Thank you spencer, understood my mistake.
I was just trying a snippet of code to check if it was joining properly but now i get it, the code is incomplete without a select from statement only.